# Encountering hibernate mapping exception coz of entity class annotation configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am getting this error because of this my application is not able to create a bean for `sessionFactory` and bean for `transactionManager`.

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.entity.Candidate"/>
```

Here I am sharing my code hope that gives better clarity.

#### web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false">
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>conceptedge</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <listener>
        <listener class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/conceptedge-persistence.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>conceptedge</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

#### sessionFactory bean:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml"></property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/interview"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>
   </bean>
```

in Dao layer, I am accessing the session as mentioned:

```
@Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Candidate> getCandidatesList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Candidate.class);
        return criteria.list();
    }
```

#### entity class

```
package com.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;    
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
public class Candidate {

    private int number;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

#### servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com" >
         <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="com.*"/>
   </context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I didn't get which rule I violated that my question scored down to -1?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add explanation of  code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to annotate your class with `@Entity` and `@Table` when using

```
<mapping class="com.entity.Candidate"/>
```

or else, you need to use sth like

```
<mapping resource="com/entity/Candidate.hbm.xml" />
```

and add the equivalent xml mapping file for your entity class.

also dont forget to initialize your sessionFactory with `AnnationConfiguration` class

```
  new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: thank you for replying but I have already given @Entity to my class. Still I am getting this exception!!

Comment: see my updated answer. please provide your code in order to help you more :)

Comment: i dont see sth like `<context:component-scan base-package="com.entity"/>` in your spring xml.

Comment: i forgot to post it, but I have those lines of code.

Comment: i guess you use hibernate 4, needless to ask right?

Comment: yes, hibernate 4 what could be the issue that I am getting this error?

Comment: just a final thought (i cant think of sth else). did you annotate your class with JPA Entity annotation? if yes, can you then try with `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean`?